# Need random image url to change and store last three images

Tags: javascript

Okay, to explain further-I am making a script that when you click the button the image will change (the first one does just fine). However, when the image changes-I need it to change the other image as well and store and display the last three random images. It's for a game.

Everything I have tried does not work. I just get the very first image src printed, not the one after clicking the button... It should update the last image.

Here is my code:

```js
var cards = new Array();
cards.push("images/img1.jpg");
cards.push("images/img2.jpg");
cards.push("images/img3.jpg");
cards.push("images/img4.jpg");
cards.push("images/img5.jpg");
cards.push("images/img6.png");
cards.push("images/img7.jpg");


function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function pickimg2() {
  document.randimg.src = cards[getRandomInt(0, cards.length - 1)];
}

var previouscards;
var previouscards = document.getElementById('cards').src;
var prec = document.write(previouscards);
document.write("<img style='width:200px;height:200px;' src=" + prec + " />"); //I Want this to change to the current image!..
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" href="#" onClick="pickimg2();return false;" value="Click Me" />
  <img id="cards" style="width:200px;height:200px;" src="+document.randimg.src+" name="randimg">
</div>
```

Comment: It seems working

Comment: This is what it outputs: "file:///C:/Users/User/game/+document.randimg.src+"... I need it to say "img1.jpg" or something along the lines.

Comment: You will fin the change in <img id="cards"> and it works fine inspect it, or I didn't get what you mean

Comment: g33k-the lines    "var prec = document.write (previouscards);
document.write("<img style='width:200px;height:200px;' src="+prec+" />"); are not changing when I click the button.

Comment: I am getting "+prec+" as the source... Not img1.jpg or img2.jpg.

Comment: because you use document.write as var and then put it inside document.write

Comment: That makes sense. Sorry I am not a Javascript pro, learning it right now. I know how to change images by clicking a button, but not store them and retrieve them. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```html
<script>
    var cards = new Array();
    cards.push("https://picsum.photos/100?image=1");
    cards.push("https://picsum.photos/100?image=2");
    cards.push("https://picsum.photos/100?image=3");
    cards.push("https://picsum.photos/100?image=4");

    var lastPics = new Array();
    var currentPic = cards[0];


    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    function pickimg2() {
     var image = cards[getRandomInt(0, cards.length - 1)];
      var innerHtml = ""
      document.randimg.src = image;
      document.getElementById("copy").src = image;
      
      lastPics.splice(0,0,image);
      if (lastPics.length > 3) {
        lastPics.pop();
      }
      lastPics.forEach(function(item){
        innerHtml = innerHtml + "<img name='copy' style='width:50px;height:50px;' src="+item+" />"
      });
      document.getElementById("lastPicsDiv").innerHTML = innerHtml;
     
    }
    </script>
    <div id="lastPicsDiv">[]</div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" href="#" onClick="pickimg2();return false;" value="Click Me"/>
      <br>
      <img id="cards" style="width:100px;height:100px;" src="https://picsum.photos/100?image=1" name="randimg">
    </div>

    <script>
    document.write("<img id='copy' style='width:100px;height:100px;' src="+currentPic+" />");
    //document.write("<p id='lastpics'>"+lastPics+"</p>"); //I Want this to change to the current image!..
    </script>
```

Comment: Umm ya! I believe it is. Let me give this a try, and I will mark as answer!

Comment: So you had to use splice? I have never used it, but I am reading on it now. Seems like a good way to accomplish this. I guess there was no way for me to get the results I needed using the code structure that I had correct?

Comment: Sure there are other ways of doing it, this is what came into my mind first. On your code you forgot to update the second img on the button click, and was missing the 'last pictures' logic

Comment: Edudjr It did exactly what I wanted it too (besides showing an extra image at the bottom which I just removed. Thank you so much for your help! Both of you guys!

Answer (score 0):

put it inside pick me function because at first it returns `undefined` because the js not written yet

```html
 <script>
    var cards = new Array();
    cards.push("images/img1.jpg");
    cards.push("images/img2.jpg");
    cards.push("images/img3.jpg");
    cards.push("images/img4.jpg");
    cards.push("images/img5.jpg");
    cards.push("images/img6.png");
    cards.push("images/img7.jpg");


    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    function pickimg2() {
      document.randimg.src = cards[getRandomInt(0, cards.length - 1)];
      
       var previouscards;
    var previouscards = document.getElementById('cards').src;
    var prec = document.write (previouscards);
    document.write("<img style='width:200px;height:200px;' src="+prec+" />"); //I Want this to change to the current image!..
    }
    </script>
    <div>
      <input type="button" href="#" onClick="pickimg2();return false;" value="Click Me"/>
        <img id="cards" style="width:200px;height:200px;" src="+document.randimg.src+" name="randimg">
    </div>
```

Comment: No, see what happens is the button disappears after the function runs once. I got the same thing moving stuff around.